# spring boot application throwing MongoSocketOpenException while connecting mongodb running on docker

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

> Hello,I have mongodb image running on docker,installed on virtual box and spring boot application on windows,when I run the application,it shows "exception opening socket".my mongodb running fine on docker,there might be problem in my application.yaml configuration.I'm defining host as a localhost,In this condition localhost will be my tomcat server which is embedded with spring boot,but here I had to assign docker to this host but I dont know how it'll be done.Help

### application.yaml

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: cms
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
```

### DemoMongoDbApplication.java

```
package com.example.demomongoDB;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoMongoDbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoMongoDbApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### stack trace

```
2019-10-24 17:30:14.370 DEBUG 12024 --- [kground-preinit] .h.v.m.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator : Loaded expression factory via original TCCL

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2019-10-24 17:30:14.573  INFO 12024 --- [           main] c.e.demomongoDB.DemoMongoDbApplication   : Starting DemoMongoDbApplication on LAPTOP-QKODI51C with PID 12024 (started by HEMRAJ in D:\D\java projects eclipse\spring boot projects\spring boot CMS\demo-mongoDB)
2019-10-24 17:30:14.575  INFO 12024 --- [           main] c.e.demomongoDB.DemoMongoDbApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-24 17:30:15.611  INFO 12024 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-24 17:30:15.636  INFO 12024 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-10-24 17:30:15.645  INFO 12024 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-24 17:30:15.648  INFO 12024 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-10-24 17:30:17.211  INFO 12024 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-24 17:30:17.226  INFO 12024 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-24 17:30:17.227  INFO 12024 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-10-24 17:30:17.377  INFO 12024 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-24 17:30:17.377  INFO 12024 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2689 ms
2019-10-24 17:30:17.866  INFO 12024 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-10-24 17:30:18.124  INFO 12024 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-10-24 17:30:18.397  WARN 12024 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2019-10-24 17:30:18.398  WARN 12024 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2019-10-24 17:30:18.432  WARN 12024 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2019-10-24 17:30:18.432  WARN 12024 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
2019-10-24 17:30:18.653  INFO 12024 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-10-24 17:30:18.658  INFO 12024 --- [           main] c.e.demomongoDB.DemoMongoDbApplication   : Started DemoMongoDbApplication in 4.974 seconds (JVM running for 5.844)
2019-10-24 17:30:22.338  INFO 12024 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ConnectTask.failed(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The remote computer refused the network connection.

    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$700(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: show how you are launching mongo container. Are you publishing ports?

Comment: I'm launching container through docker command

Comment: docker run -d --name mongodb --net cms-application -p 27017:27017 mongo:3.4.10